# How to use ramda mergeRight in Typescript and respect interface definitions

Tags: node.js, typescript, ramda.js

I'm trying to make a copy of an object and change properties using Rambda's `mergeRight` function.  The problem is it allows me to merge in properties that do not exist in the interface definition.

```
import {mergeRight} from "ramda";

export interface User {
    readonly userId: string
    readonly username: string
}

const user: User = {
    userId: "12345",
    username: "SomeUser"
}

//I want this to be a compile time error, because "something" is not a property of User interface
const updatedUser: User = mergeRight(user, {something: "3"})
```

Is there any way I can ensure that the properties I am merging are part of the `User` type, without having to specify an entire new User object (thus defeating the advantage of mergeRight)?  This would prevent a simple typo from causing a runtime error that is difficult to debug.

Ideally I would like Typescript to detect this at compile time

Comment: idk if they've made updates, but last i checked ramda (~a year ago), they didn't have comprehensive typings.. but `Object.assign` and the spread operator work fine for this case.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To filter out keys that are not part of user, use R.pick to take just keys that exist in `User` from the new object.

This will only effect the root level of the object, and not deeper mismatches.

```js
const { pick, keys, mergeDeepRight } = R

const user = {
  userId: "12345",
  username: "SomeUser"
}

const getUserKeys = pick(keys(user))

//I want this to be an error, because "something" is not a property of User interface
const updatedUser = mergeDeepRight(user, getUserKeys({
  something: "3"
}))

console.log(updatedUser)
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/ramda/0.27.0/ramda.js"></script>
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, interesting solution.  In this case the mergeDeepRight call will have no effect.  What I am really looking for is a way for Typescript to detect that we are trying to assign an invalid property at compile time.  I should have specified I am using Node.  I will update my question.

Comment: I will accept your answer, as this would also be effective in Javascript as well and my solution actually has nothing to do with Ramda

Answer (score 1):

It seems that simply casting the anonymous object as User will give the error I want.  That's good enough for my use case.

```
//This causes a compile time error
const updatedUser: User = mergeRight(user, {something: "3"} as User)

//This does not
const updatedUser2: User = mergeRight(user, {userId: "3"} as User)
```

Comment: type assertion is not going to help as the OP doesn't want extra props to be merged...

Comment: This works for me because it provides an error if the prop being merged is not part of the interface